# Automatically add the discussion tag to questions migrated from SO

Tags: feature-request, tags

I recently ran into an issue editing a question on meta to correct a typo.  When I went to submit it, it complained that the tags were not correct.  It was missing a required tag.  If the tags are really required, then they should be added when the question is migrated.  I suggest marking them as discussion as that seems to be the most common type of question asked on the sites that gets migrated to meta.  If the question is mistagged it can then be retagged as needed.  This would make the migrated questions tags consistent with those of questions asked on meta directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably should also make sure that there isn't any moderator specific tags.

Answer (score 0):

or maybe Support?

Comment: I've moved a **lot** of questions that get flagged on SO, and the vast majority of them are discussion.  Support is probably 2nd, but it's pretty distant.